# How to replace usages of deprecated imp.load_dynamic?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-importlib

The `imp` module is deprecated (since version 3.4), however some parts of the infrastructure (e.g. [`pyximport`](https://github.com/cython/cython/blob/7f26ba41ced0a95e2aef6ed608302fe743d836dd/pyximport/pyximport.py#L216)) still use [`imp.load_dynamic`](https://docs.python.org/3.0/library/imp.html#imp.load_dynamic), which leads to deprecation-warnings with newer Python versions.

Internally, `imp.load_dynamic` uses [`importlib`-machinery](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/e471e72977c83664f13d041c78549140c86c92de/Lib/imp.py#L330-L342):

```
from importlib._bootstrap import _load
def load_dynamic(name, path, file=None):
    """**DEPRECATED**
    Load an extension module.
    """
    import importlib.machinery
    loader = importlib.machinery.ExtensionFileLoader(name, path)

    # Issue #24748: Skip the sys.modules check in _load_module_shim;
    # always load new extension
    spec = importlib.machinery.ModuleSpec(
        name=name, loader=loader, origin=path)
    return _load(spec)
```

But it feels silly to duplicate this code (which [at least once](https://bugs.python.org/issue24748) had to be improved) for all kind of projects.

`importlib`'s documentation [proposes](https://docs.python.org/3/library/importlib.html#importing-a-source-file-directly) the following:

```
import importlib.util
import sys
def alternative_load_dynamic(name, path, file=None):
    spec = importlib.util.spec_from_file_location(name, path)
    module = importlib.util.module_from_spec(spec)
    sys.modules[name] = module
    spec.loader.exec_module(module)
    return sys.modules[name]
```

While it has the advantage of not using the private API compared to the first implementation (i.e. `_load`) and gets the behavior at the core of [issue #24748](https://bugs.python.org/issue24748) right, it is not a drop-in replacement for `imp.load_dynamic`:

- this alternative can more: it can also load pure python modules (`*.py` or `*.pyc`).
- this alternative can less: it can only load dynamic modules with ending `*.so` (or `*.pyd` on Windows), but not for example `foo.my_ending`.

What are other options to replace `imp.load_dynamic`?

Comment: Wait so what's wrong with:

    import importlib.machinery
 loader = importlib.machinery.ExtensionFileLoader(name, path)
    spec = importlib.machinery.ModuleSpec(name=name, loader=loader, origin=path)
 module = importlib.util.module_from_spec(spec)
    spec.loader.exec_module(module)

? Yes it only loads modules with *.so (or *.pyd on Windows), but isn't this what imp.load_dynamic was doing anyway (loads a "dynamically loadable shared library") ?

Comment: @AndreiGheorghe there is nothing wrong with it, only that it is a little bit silly to duplicate code of a deprecated function. I'm no expert in this field, and probably later, for python version XY, the code would not properly work in some cases. It will be fixed in the deprecated function, but not in the one I have written...

Answer (score -2):

How about `importlib.import_module` ?

It also notes:

> If you are dynamically importing a module that was created since the interpreter began execution (e.g., created a Python source file), you may need to call invalidate_caches() in order for the new module to be noticed by the import system.

https://docs.python.org/3/library/importlib.html#importlib.import_module

Comment: `import_module` is doing something different. One important part of `load_dynamic` is that it bypasses the `sys.path` and the file is given explicitly, there are also other differences, so `load_dynamic`  cannot be replaced by `import_module`